# Thread sleeps for too long

Tags: java, multithreading

I wrote a simple program and noticed that my threads are too fast for me to run JVisualVM, mark which app I want to monitor, plug in and look at threads. I then made them sleep. And noticed tools now report them as only sleeping (or almost only sleeping). Even though they work. This begs the question: why?!

```
    new Thread(() -> {
        while(true) {
            System.out.println("not sleeping");
            try {
                Thread.sleep(0,1);
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }, "not sleeping!").start();
```

This thread should sleep for 1 nanosecond, yet take a look at how it's reported by JVisualVM:

[image: ran for a minute but ran 5s]

After running for 57s it reports 5s running time and rest as sleeping - a bug or is my understanding wrong?

It's not just JVisualVM:

```
$ while true; do jstack 8277 | grep -A 2 not; done              [% 20:34:27]
"not sleeping!" #10 prio=5 os_prio=0 tid=0x00007f5ea82d1000 nid=0x2078 waiting on condition [0x00007f5e917c6000]
   java.lang.Thread.State: TIMED_WAITING (sleeping)
    at java.lang.Thread.sleep(Native Method)
```

`jstack` also only occasionally reports this thread as RUNNING. I'd expect different proportions, so please help me understand.

Comment: You can't rely on a thread sleeping for the exact amount of time you specify. 57s is... excessive, though.

Comment: @AndyTurner I do agree. Even more with nanos. But I didn't expect for the proportions to be... well, reversed. It's mostly sleeping.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't expect to sleep for as short as 1 nanosecond. When you request to sleep you will do a task switch and it make take some time until it can be scheduled back, especially if you have other processes/threads. So if the workload of the thread is very low then it may end up spending most of the time sleeping.

It is also probable that your sleeping time is rounded up at some layer to a multiple of system's time granularity. At least in some Java implementations the nanos argument [is mostly ignored](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/6-b14/java/lang/Thread.java#Thread.sleep%28long%29).

Comment: I requested 1 ns to make it minimum possible. I never expected 1ns, since pretty much all Java methods with nanos state in docs that nanos depend on the system. Nevertheless, for others who would like to check if that is so, look up number of context switches (pidstat or cat thread status from /proc). Thanks for source link and answer! Increasing the workload (Fibonacci for random n) made the thread mostly runnable.